# MS Outlook 2010 if image not available, substitute with text

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-signature

In Outlook 2010, I use an image as my signature to make it look nice (please don't criticize me for this!).  I was wondering if it is possible to substitute the image with text when the image cannot be displayed (it is a rare event, but sometimes doesn't work) like with HTML when the image isn't available?  If possible, I would prefer not to use macros, but am willing to use them if need be.